# How can I use SQL Server Table Views as Rails Models (Read Only)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, freetds, sql-view, tiny-tds

I'm using SQL Server as my database for my Rails project. I'm trying to create some models to use for a 3rd party database and only want to read from this database.  So I made a view of the table I wanted to create an object for and then I wanted to point my active record model to it.  However, in rails console I don't get back expected results.  The only example that gives back some correct information is when I do a `count` on the object as shown in Example 3 below.

I'm using the following gems to connect to my SQL Server:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

Also I have installed freetds-dev 0.91-6build1

**Example 1**

```
2.2.2 :004 > Game.all
  Game Load (268.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [games].* FROM [games]'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, #<Game >, ...]>
```

**Example 2**

```
2.2.2 :001 > Game.first
  SQL (1.1ms)  USE [Incoming]
  Game Load (1.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [games].* FROM [games] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '0'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [games].* FROM [games] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '0'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [games].* FROM [games] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:336:in `each'
    ...
    ...
```

**Example 3**

```
2.2.2 :008 > Game.count
   (4.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [games]'
 => 12541
```

**incoming_model.rb**

```
class IncomingModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name_prefix = "Incoming.dbo."
  establish_connection "incoming_#{Rails.env}".to_sym
end
```

**game_model.rb**

```
class Game < IncomingModel
  self.table_name = 'games'
end
```

**database.yml**

```
incoming_development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: games-data
  port: 1433
  database: Incoming
  username: ****
  password: ****
  pool: 5
  timeout: 15000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found that I needed to specify a primary key for the table.  So here is the addition I made.

```
class Game < IncomingModel
  self.table_name = 'games'
  self.primary_key = 'game_id', 'this_other_column'
end
```

I also had to incorporate for my needs the gem `composite_primary_keys`, however, that might be more than what some developers will need.  Thanks to anyone that took the time to try and help troubleshoot this issue!

Comment: That worked for me also. I'm now able to access a view from an sql database belonging to a non rails app.