# Can you use establish_connection to connect to an SQL view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to pull data from an SQL database belonging to Sage CRM. I am able to connect and work with the data tables. I need to work with one of the views in the database and can't seem to get that connection.

Here is how I'm connecting to the tables.

```
class CrmTable < ActiveRecord::Base

      self.abstract_class = true
      def self.table_name_prefix
        'dbo_'
      end
   # establish_connection "crm_tables_#{Rails.env}"
      establish_connection "crm_tables"
end

class Address < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Address"
end

class Opportunity < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Opportunity"
end
```

That connects me to the Address and Opportunity tables with no issues.

However, I want to be able to access the SQL view of database/views/dbo.vPerson.

I tried variations on the following:

```
class Vperson < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Vperson"
end
```

However, I don't seem to be getting any records. I tried putting the following in my view but it was nil

```
<% @view_name = CrmTable::Vperson.all %>

<% @view_name.inspect %>
```

Is it possible to establish an active record connection to a view? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel STUPID.. I forgot the = in the <% @view_name.inspect %> line.. It should be <%= @view_name.inspect %>. That explains why I wasn't seeing anything..

I did see another question that mentioned a need to add a primary key when you are connecting to views.

[How can I use SQL Server Table Views as Rails Models (Read Only)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118567/how-can-i-use-sql-server-table-views-as-rails-models-read-only)